# Not working Tailwind @apply in Laravel Nova tool

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova v3.27.0 and tailwind's classes are works fine, but I cant create tailwind component. The `apply` is not working.

```
// Nova Tool CSS
.btn{
    @apply font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
}
.btn-big{
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Gets me this in inspector

```
.btn{
}
.btn-big{
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

are you doing a rebuild after you add this? perhaps you need to run something like this:

`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

or does Nova use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix?

in which case you can run

`npm run dev` or `npm run production` to generate the css with the new .btn class